# Understanding difference in rotation and translation

Tags: image-processing, camera-pose, geometry

Hi I am a newbie to the field so please don't mind a rookie question. I have read multiple articles and want to ensure my understanding is correct.
I have following two images. In the second image, the object of interest hasn't moved , its just the camera. Is that why its called rotation? How would translation look like in this image? If the floor had moved to other location, would that be called translation?

Lets say there was a dog on the floor and it moved from location A to location B, would that be considered a translation?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I mean, you can just look up these terms in the dictionary. Wikipedia has extensive pages about both [rotation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_(mathematics)) and [translation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_(geometry)).

Comment: I’m the images, the camera rotates. If you move the dog you translate the dog, and you might also be rotating the dog at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Homography has an interpretation as a change of perspective or movement of the "camera". I think your example casually refers to the apparent "rotation" of the camera in the homography mapping. However, usually, by [rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix), we mean rotating the image around the origin, whereas the [translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_(geometry)) changes the locations of each pixel by a given direction and distance.

Homography $H(\cdot)$ and rotation (by the rotation matrix) of a "pyramid" $X$ illustrated:
[image]